# Dynamic X-Axis Point print in Core Plot

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios5, ios4, core-plot

I have create a simple core plot example, that is working fine, but I need to x-Axis value that generate dynamically, I want to Develop Graph (Date)->(Blood Pressure) graph, there is Blood pressure interval is fixed but date is dynamic. So how can I put X-Axis (date) value dynamically?

Answer (score 0):

Once your datasource has access to the data you want to plot, you can use the plot space method `-scaleToFitPlots:` to fit the plot space ranges around the data. If you already know the range of data, you can set the `xRange` and `yRange` directly.